# Browser caching behaviour for doc/xls file

Tags: security, caching, document

I'm currently wondering about how the various document are cached by browser / intermediary network device.
I saw server's response with xls files and no cache HTTP header, but I cannot find them in my browser cache.
Does someone have an explanation? Is it a special case in the caching policy?

Comment: you saw no cache header and they weren't cached?

Comment: No there was no cache/pragma header. I'm wondering if that's a browser setting (here: firefox). That's not the first time I'm viewing this but I can't explain it.